# Load testing with html pages having Web API calls in buttons(login, registration)

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

[image]

I recorded application. It record login get method page as the only html page. login post method pages not recorded instead it record as one authorization manager and some APIs. How can I load testing using only html pages. Now my record script seems full of APIs instead of .html pages. I asked to my developers. They told "In submit buttons they call APIs related to those pages". Help me to get out of this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately your question `How can I load testing using only html pages. ` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You **must not record** these requests to `.js` and `woff2` as this is not how real browsers behave.

Real browsers execute main request to what you call "html page" followed by concurrent download of "embedded resources", in your case JavaScript and Font files. [To make your JMeter test to behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) you need to:

1. Exclude these requests from recording. Click "Add suggested excludes" button in the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

   [image: JMeter Suggested Excludes]
2. When you finish recording and will be preparing your script for execution add [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) to your Test Plan, switch to the "Advanced" tab and tick `Retrieve All Embedded Resources` and `Parallel Downloads` boxes

   [image: JMeter HTTP Request Defaults Embedded Resources]

This way you will be properly handing JavaScripts, Fonts, images, styles, whatever in your load test.